# Why is $f(x)=x^{2}+1$ a primitive recursive function?

Tags: computability, recursion

I'm trying to find out why $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N},f(x)=x^{2}+1$ is a primitive recursive function.

For $f(S(y))$ I can't seem to get it to fit the axioms known to me about primitive recursion.

I would appreciate your input.

Cheers!

Gregor

Comment: Can you show that addition and multiplication are primitive recursive, then conclude from there that the sum and product of two primitive recursive functions is primitive recursive?

Comment: Just a minor detail. Here at stackexchange, users are asked to [avoid greetings in a post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). This allows other users to get a first glimpse at the actual problem in the preview of your post. I edited your post accordingly. (To state the obvious: Politeness is still key.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of given a proof, let me give you a guideline. (See how far you get and if you are stuck, feel free to ask for additional help.)

- Show that $add(m,n)$ is primitive recursive
- Note that $mult(m,0) = 0$, $mult(m,S(n)) = add(mult(m,n),m)$
- Using primitive recursion (and projection) and $add(m,n)$ to show that $mult(m,n)$ is primitive recursive
- Conclude that $f$ is primitive recursive